# Hierarchy correspondance between hardware and program in CUDA model

Tags: cuda

In my current understanding, the hardware hierarchy of CUDA model is GPU card -> Streaming Multiprocessors (SMs) -> cores, and the program hierarchy is kernel-> grid -> block -> warp -> single thread. I want to know the correspondence between the hardware and program hierarchy. That is, Is a kernel in general composed of several grids? is grid contained in the GPU card or in the SMs? if grid is contained in the GPU card, can the the GPU card contain only one grid or multiple grids? Does block correspond to a SMS? Can a SMs contains only one block or multiple blocks? Can a block span several SMs? Can a core execute only one thread or multiple threads? etc.

Comment: Have you read the [documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#programming-model)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A kernel is a function that runs on the GPU.

The grid is all threadblocks associated with a kernel launch.  A kernel launch creates a single grid.
A grid can run on the entire GPU devices (all SM's in the GPU).
A grid is composed of threadblocks.

Threadblocks are groups of threads.  Threads are grouped into warps (32 threads) for execution purposes, so we can also say threadblocks are groups of warps.

Threadblocks (the warps they contain) execute on an SM.  Once a threadblock begins executing on a particular SM, it stays on that SM and will not migrate to another SM.

SMs are composed of cores.  Each core executes one thread.  The core execution engine may have the ability to handle multiple instructions at a time, so it can actually handle more than one thread, but not from the same warp.    This part gets complicated and it's not essentialy to good beginner understanding of how a GPU works, so it's convenient and useful to think of a core only handling one thread at any given instant (instruction cycle).

An SM can handle multiple blocks simultaneously.

Please don't post questions that contain many questions.
Questions on SO should show some research effort.

Good research effort for questions like these would be take take some basic webinars from the [nvidia webinar page](https://developer.nvidia.com/gpu-computing-webinars), which will only require a couple hours of study.

Try these two first:

GPU Computing using CUDA C – An Introduction (2010)
An introduction to the basics of GPU computing using CUDA C. Concepts will be illustrated with walkthroughs of code samples. No prior GPU Computing experience required

GPU Computing using CUDA C – Advanced 1 (2010)
First level optimization techniques such as global memory optimization, and processor utilization. Concepts will be illustrated using real code examples

Comment: Thank you. I post this question in this manner because I need a quick answer for some reason. I searched and read some materials that seems to be able to familiarize myself in "a couple hours", but all these materials fails to give me a clear correspondence between HW and SW hierarchy; they only make me more and more confused. That's why I had to ask here and contained in the post so many questions.

Comment: A few offtopic comments. Someone may think I should take a deep study of some comprehensive introduction materials first such as those listed at the end of the answer. I stronly agree that this is a good approach to a deep and full understanding of CUDA architechture, I even hope I could read textbooks about modern computer architechture and operation system that underlies the CUDA technology. But I can't do that for some reason. People always have to do something for some reason that other people can not understand, or even despise. The only thing I can say is: ...

Comment: show some mutual understanding, please. No one can say for absolute sure that s/he will never meet this circumstances. When you start to despise, or downvote other people, consider for some time if you had similar circumstances of difficulty in the past, or maybe in the future. OK, thank you very much for the answer. This is much better than materials I had read in the last 12 hours.

Comment: I didn't downvote your question.  This is an open forum.  Anybody can downvote anything.  I can tell you are relatively new to SO (and CUDA) and so I'm offering advice that I think will help you with SO (and CUDA).  And by the way, the downvote mechanism works.  It encourages people to improve their questions and improve their answers.  I have been downvoted in the past.  Don't feel bad about it.